# How to enter variable into string?

Tags: php, string, variables

Here's my code:

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents('http://example.com/bin/serp.php?engine=google&phrase=$name');
```

It doesn't appear to be using `$name` correctly.  How would I add that variable into my string like I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the single quotes to double quotes. PHP variables are *not* interpolated when in single quotes.

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("http://example.com/bin/serp.php?engine=google&phrase=$name");
```

You can also use concatenation here:

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents('http://example.com/bin/serp.php?engine=google&phrase=' . $name);
```

Answer (score 3):

Either change the single quotes around your string to double quotes:

```
"http://example.com/bin/serp.php?engine=google&phrase=$name"
```

Or use string concatenation with the `.` operator:

```
'http://example.com/bin/serp.php?engine=google&phrase=' . $name
```

Both of these techniques are mentioned on [PHP's Strings documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).